# How can i build function that can receive DatagridView.Rows or Datagridview.SelectedRows?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The function must support two case 
first case, it can receive All rows in the datagridview.
and Second case, It can receive only selected rows.

```
   If Case_A Then 

        PrintLabel(dtg.SelectedRows)
  End If

  If Case_B Then
        PrintLabel(dtg.Rows)
  End If
```

Function PrinLabel may be something like these

```
   Public Function PrintLabel(ByVal dtgvNeedPrint As DataGridViewRowCollection) As Boolean

      For Each dtgRow As DataGridViewRow In dtgvNeedPrint
         ''// Do something.
      End 

    End Function
```

But it's error.Because of  **dtg.SelectedRows** isn't **DataGridViewRowCollection**. Type isn't matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use either type as neither inherits the other.  Instead, declare your parameter as type `IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewRow)` and then you can call `Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)` on either collection and pass the result to your method.  An `IEnumerable` is all you need anyway, if what you intend to do is loop over the list with a `For Each` loop.

```
Public Function PrintLabel(rows As IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewRow)) As Boolean
    For Each row In rows
        '' Do something.
    End
End Function


If Case_A Then
    PrintLabel(dtg.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)())
End If

If Case_B Then
    PrintLabel(dtg.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)())
End If
```